# File Upload optional value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to make my file upload code optional. This code is returning `null reference exception` handled by user.

How can I make it optional if user does not choose the file the null value should be submitted to the database?

here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AdulLiteracyTeachers adulliteracyteachers, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
    if (files.Length != null)
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {       
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "File(s) Already Exist";
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Image with this Name Already Exist");
                ViewBag.Error = TempData["Image with this Name Already Exist"];
            }
            else
            {
                file.SaveAs(path);
                adulliteracyteachers.Image = file.FileName;
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Add(adulliteracyteachers);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
        }

    ViewBag.DistID = new SelectList(db.Districts, "DistID", "DistName", adulliteracyteachers.DistID);
    return View(adulliteracyteachers);
}
```

Comment: still got the pRoblem Object reference not set to an instance of an object. null referece exception unhandl by user

Answer (score 1):

```
if(files != null && files.length > 0)
```

it errors out because files object is null.